# Function variable not available when require page through another class method

Tags: php, oop

I want to be able to require page through class methods. The problem is, when I require the page via normal require statement, all variable are accessible on the required page but if I use another class to require that page, variables are no longer accessible.

I have two page, index.php and other.php.

index.php:

```
class Myclass {
    public function test(){
        $test='hello World';
        $other=new other;
        $other->other_page('other.php'); //if I change this line to require 'other.php' variables are accessible.
    }
}


class other {
    public function other_page($page){
        require $page;
    }
}

$class=new Myclass;
$class->test();
```

other.php

```
<?php
echo $test;
```

index.php is giving undefined index error. But if I changes the:

```
$other->other_page('other.php');
```

to

```
require 'other.php';
```

everything works just fine. I can make those varible available by passing them to

```
other::other_page()
```

In both case, everything is same. Then why class behave differently and is there any other way to make variables accessible other than passing them to

```
other::other_page()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of doubt always refer to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

> For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well ... However, within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope.

[And](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

The problem is that your script `other.php` inherits the scope of the `other_page()` method. Inside of this method there is no local variable `$test` defined. That's where your error originates from. Now it should be logical why a direct require in your `MyClass`es `test()` method works. The included file inherits the scope of the method and within it's scope there is indeed a `$test` variable.

That's the general problem. I would suggest that you rethink your design. Instead of relying that randomly a certain scope is inherited, explicitly pass the scope to the script you want to include.

```
<?php

// Controller.php
class Controller {

    public function test()
    {
        $test = 'Hello World';
        // You would probably want to pass that via Dependency-Injection and
        // not as a hardcoded dependecny
        $retriever = new PageRetriever;

        // Only the contents of the second argument are passed
        // to the getPage() method
        echo $retriever->getPage('page.php', ['test' => $test]);
    }

}

// PageRetriever.php
class PageRetriever {

    public function getPage( $page, $args = [] )
    {
        $contents = null;

        // Extract the contents of the $args array into
        // the methods local scope
        extract($args);

        // Initiate output buffering, so that the contents
        // of the script is not immediately displayed
        ob_start();
        require $page;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $contents;
    }

}
```

That's only a dead simple implementation to demonstrate what I am talking about. Here you have a clean seperated scope. You know that only variables are available within your `PageRetriever` that have explicitly been passed.

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks. For the Help. I am developing a MVC framework mostly for learning purpose, Would you like to give me some tips? [link](https://github.com/mayankiiitm/mvc)

Comment: I will definitely take a look some time! :)

Answer (score 0):

i'll give you a simple example, from that you can understand accessing mechanism

first.php

```
<?php    
class first {    
    private $name;
    function __construct() {
        $this->name="name";
    }

    function  changeName(){
        $this->name="newName";
    }

    function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }    
}    
?>
```

second.php

```
<?php
    include 'first.php';
    $firstObject=new first;
    echo $firstObject->getName().'<br>';
    $firstObject->changeName();
    echo $firstObject->getName();

?>
```

In your case if you use `require 'other.php'` then that content is including in `Myclass` class's `test()` funcation. In that location `$test` is defined.

But when you are using `$other->other_page('other.php');` then that content is including in `other`  class's `other_page($page)` function. In that location `$test` is not defined.

Comment: rehman I understand the problem and access mechanism. I want two know why my code is not working when I am including the page through a class call but works when required directly.

Comment: @MayankKumar - Answer edited. Please read last two paragraphs.